# Where is my text file being saved to?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made a basic save to text file program. It works perfectly, but I just can't find where the created text files are being stored. Does anyone have any idea where they are stored?

All necessary permissions have been granted.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final EditText enter = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText));
    final TextView show = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView));
    Button b = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button));
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             final String s = enter.getText().toString();
             writeToFile(s, s);
             show.setText(readFromFile(s));

         }
     }
    );
}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
     int id = item.getItemId();

     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
         return true;
     }

     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 private void writeToFile(String name, String data) {
     try {
         OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(name + ".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
         outputStreamWriter.write(data);
         outputStreamWriter.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
     }
 }

 private String readFromFile(String name) {

     String ret = "";

     try {
         InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(name + ".txt");

         if (inputStream != null) {
             InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
             String receiveString = "";
             StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

             while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                 stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
             }

             inputStream.close();
             ret = stringBuilder.toString();
         }
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
     } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
     }

     return ret;
 }


 public static void Save(File file, String[] data) {
     FileOutputStream fos = null;
     try {
         fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     try {
         try {
             for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 fos.write(data[i].getBytes());
                 if (i < data.length - 1) {
                     fos.write("\n".getBytes());
                 }
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     } finally {
         try {
             fos.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Why don't you look it up in the android docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `context.getFileStreamPath()` to return the path to the location of your saved file. According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)):

```
public abstract File getFileStreamPath (String name)
```

> Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where
>   a file created with openFileOutput(String, int) is stored.

Answer (score 0):

The file is being written to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). This is an area that is private to your app. It cannot be viewed by other apps or desktop programs, except on rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command 
ActivityName.this.getFileDir().getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing this code on an emulator, you can shell into the emulator and likely find your file in this directory

```
/data/data/<appid>/files
```

Where `<appid>` is the application id specified in build.gradle